# .tif to PCraster format conversion in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, qgis-3, convert

I am using QGIS 3.2 and trying to convert a resampled .tif file into PCRaster format which is used for a downstream model.

Unfortunately, when I try to export the resampled.tif file into PCRaster format i get the following error:

> "Unsupported Data Source: resampled.map is not a supported raster data source"

Can anyone help to export my tif to PCRaster?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that on menu "Raster" > "conversion" > "Translate", and when setting your options you have to specify the field "Output data type".

Ex: if your map has only integers you can set Int32, or if you have real numbers "Float32"

Then you have to change the "Converted field", set file name and save Location, there you specify the ".MAP" file extension